# Submitting Hadoop Job on remote Hadoop cluster from web application (servlet)

Tags: servlets, hadoop

I have configured a Hadoop cluster with 2 nodes of Linux boxes and I have a servlet application running on Tomcat on third Linux box. My goal is to submit Hadoop from web app. When I submit job from Eclipse then I am able to submit job on Hadoop remotely. I am getting following exception in case of servlet. Please suggest

'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1414)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:231)
     at $Proxy11.getSystemDir(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster$1.run(Cluster.java:141)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster$1.run(Cluster.java:139)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getFileSystem(Cluster.java:139)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1040)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1062)
     at servlets.JobDriver.doProcess(JobDriver.java:112)
     at servlets.JobDriver.doGet(JobDriver.java:42)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)'

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it seems the user from your servlet making the job submission has no permission to submit the job to the cluster:

```
$Proxy11.getSystemDir(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster$1.run(Cluster.java:141) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster$1.run(Cluster.java:139) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getFileSystem(Cluster.java:139) at  
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1040) at
```

Make sure only the admin group submits from servlet by checking the servlet Session.